# Disable Opencart Affiliate Module Completely

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm Using OpenCart 2.1.0.2 and getting bot affiliate account daily 20 to 25 accounts. so i'm planning to disable completely affiliate module of Opencart , Please, anyone can help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Opencart does not provide default functionality to disable affiliate account completely. You have to do manually. Or you will need help to another experienced developer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a pull request to opencart that adds an option to disable the functionality: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/7166.  Once that's merged (or if you patch your code with it), you can shut affiliate marketing off in your store settings.

[image]

Comment: I /think/ what happened is they closed my PR after writing this functionality a different way (though I'm not certain) and you may be able to set config_affiliate_status to 0 in recent versions somewhere in the admin panel's configuration pages.  I'm not so enthusiastic about opencart these days after they've denied every attempt I made to upstream things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Login to CPanel, go to File Manager and go to your Opencart installation folder. Navigate to /catalog/controller/. Inside this folder you will find the folder "affiliate". Rename or delete it. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, in your Settings (of your admin dashboard), make sure they require your approval. This way they don't just get an automatically-enabled affiliate account after they sign up for it (i think this should be an option in your version, but if not, follow the rest of this post anyway.)

Second, just remove the links and the tpl pages altogether to it, so that way they don't click nor sign up for it.  For example, using the default template folder (default) navigate to:

1. `template/account/affiliate.tpl` - this file can be deleted
2. `template/affiliate` - delete the affiliate folder altogether
3. `template/module/affiliate.tpl` - this file can be deleted

Please make sure you backup these files anyway just in case anything. You should be done with **bots/spammers** trying to sign up now as there are no pages they can land on to sign up for affiliate-related things.

There are other things that can be done, too, but given the way you formatted your question and the vagueness in what you attempted thus far, this may be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I followed: Deleted both folders to disable affiliate pages /index.php?route=affiliate/login

1. /public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/affiliate/
2. /public_html/catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/affiliate/

But still getting 20 to 30 affiliate account registration daily.

Note: I'm using journal theme. – R

Answer (score 0):

From the opencart admin left bar menu go to Extension -> Extensions -> Modules. Check if there's a module named Affiliate (by default it should be right below the Account module). Uninstall it.